# Pyodbc - SQL Injection in Upsert

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc, upsert

I have used ? placeholder to pass list of values in Python for Insert/Update.

Now, I am trying to upsert the records with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135898/multi-row-upsert-insert-or-update-from-python)

Code:

```
table_name = 'ddf.ddf_actuals'

columns_list = df.columns.tolist()
columns_list_query = f'({(",".join(columns_list))})'
sr_columns_list = [f'Source.{i}' for i in columns_list]
sr_columns_list_query = f'({(",".join(sr_columns_list))})'
up_columns_list = [f'{i}=Source.{i}' for i in columns_list]
up_columns_list_query = f'{",".join(up_columns_list)}'

rows_to_insert = [row.tolist() for idx, row in final_list.iterrows()]
rows_to_insert = str(rows_to_insert).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')')[1:][:-1]


query = f"MERGE INTO {table_name} as Target \
USING (SELECT * FROM \
(VALUES {rows_to_insert}) \
AS s {columns_list_query}\
) AS Source \
ON Target.stationcode=Source.stationcode AND Target.date=Source.date \
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN \
INSERT {columns_list_query} VALUES {sr_columns_list_query} \
WHEN MATCHED THEN \
UPDATE SET {up_columns_list_query};"
c.execute(query)

c.commit()
```

Issue is `rows_to_insert` has string values with single quotes. I tried to replace single quote with `\'`, but did not work as expected. Since `\'` is an escape sequence for Python, not for SQL, did not work. Even  replacing with `''` did not work

Since I am executing list of list, not sure how placeholder `?` can be used here

Comment: I had to solve this same problem and posted my solution on the post you linked - here's a link to my response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64067438/10342097